# how to echo image using php variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to echo image which is stored in array

```
public function getData(){
    $page =  $_GET['page'];
    $this->load->model('Mainpage');
    $countries = $this->Mainpage->getCountry($page);


    foreach($countries as $country){

         echo ('<img>'.$country->link.'</img>');
             echo '<p>'.$country->news.'</p>'; 
     }
    exit;
}
```

Here `$country->link` stores path of image but I am not able to image please help.
I am trying this in codeigniter framework.

Comment: valid html would help

Comment: means what should i do? @Dagon

Comment: learn html, before php

Comment: Why not use codeigniter img() in the html helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img

Comment: As Dagon suggestion http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the HTML image tag correctly, change the line,

```
echo ('<img>'.$country->link.'</img>');
```

for

```
echo ('<img src="'.$country->link.'">');
```

**Added after comments...**

Page location - 127.0.0.1/viralhai
Image location - 127.0.0.1/viralhai/assests/postimage/post3.jpg
`$country->link` - ../assests/postimage/post1.jpg

`../` in a path takes you up a directory level.
When you request the image `../assests/postimage/post1.jpg` on page `127.0.0.1/viralhai` the browser looks at `127.0.0.1/assests/postimage/post3.jpg`. See how `viralhai` was removed?

In this specific situation you can prefix and then remove the first two characters of the returned file path like,

```
 echo ('<img src="/viralhai'.substr($country->link, 2).'">');
```

I spent about 5 seconds on google so this might not be the best resource but there is some good knowledge for you here - https://www.kirupa.com/html5/all_about_file_paths.htm. Scroll down to "The Absolute Path Way" which is how I would recommend storing your image paths.

Comment: not working @Steve i already tried this code

Comment: @ViralHai Can you show us a `var_dump($country);`?

Comment: You said "$country->link stores path of image", what do you get when you `echo $country->link`?

Comment: object(stdClass)#22 (6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["type"]=> string(3) "all" ["news"]=> string(53) "The lguana Scene From Last Night's planet Earth II..." ["link"]=> string(30) "../assests/postimage/post1.jpg" ["images"]=> string(0) "" ["reserve"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: var_dump($country);

Comment: Well, as long as that is what is in the `$country`-variable, `$country->link` should give you the correct info to put into `<img src=` - so the question becomes, what are you doing wrong, or is the path correct? Inspect the element in a browser, and check to see where the path goes that is in the `src`, and if it's the right path. I see you have a typo in there, but if the folder is named `assests` then that's fine.

Comment: path is correct firebug saying failed to load image

Comment: You're using a relative path for your image which isn't helping. Without knowing your file structure it's pretty much impossible to help you. What is the complete URL for the image, including domain?

Comment: maybe the image is broken

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/viralhai/assests/postimage/post3.jpg

Comment: ...and what is the url of the page you are on when you try to view the image?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/viralhai/

Comment: Updated answer for you...

Comment: thanks steve yoou made my day...now its working

Comment: No problem. The solution is a bit of a hack though, make sure you read up on file paths!

Answer (score -1):

How about changing your code like this:

```
public function getData(){
    $page =  $_GET['page'];
    $this->load->model('Mainpage');
    $countries = $this->Mainpage->getCountry($page);


    foreach($countries as $country){

         $country = '<img src="'.$country->link.'" />'); 
         return $country;
     }
    return false;
}
```

Tell me what this gives you!

Comment: thats invalid html

Comment: @Dagon I apologize for not including the = (equals sign)